# I can no longer add a new site in vagrant box

Tags: nginx, vagrant, homestead

All of a sudden I can no longer add a new local site in my vagrant VM, but my previous sites work perfectly. I am using Laravel Homestead with Vagrant.

What I always do to register a new site is :

1. Create a directory in /home/vagrant/Code/mysitedir and add an index.php in it
2. serve mylocaldomain.app /home/vagrant/Code/mysitedir
3. Add mylocaldomain.app to my hosts file, eg: 192.168.10.10  mylocaldomain.app

And then I am able to visit mylocaldomain.app and see my index.php file output, so everything's working.

**However**, this time when I viited mylocaldomain.app I am getting an error ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION on Chrome, site not found on Firefox, etc.

I also checked line by line my etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mylocaldomain.app to have the exactly same structure as one of my other working local sites.

When I run vagrant global-status, I get the following:

```
id       name   provider state  directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or,
you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were
started with an older version of Vagrant.
```

What am I doing wrong ? I reboot, I did vagrant halt and vagrant up, vagrant reload, nothing works. I didn't try provision though, because I heard it's destructive. Is there anything I can try to solve this ?

Comment: which extension are you using ? change your `mylocaldomain.app` with `mylocaldomain.localdomain` and you should be ok

Comment: I am using .app extension on all of my other sites and they always worked normally (and they still work now). I tried your suggestion : `serve mylocaldomain.localdomain /home/vagrant/Code/tmp`, But I can't view it on the browser, same error (my hosts file is also updated for mylocaldomain.localdomain).